# Header File Difficulties

Tags: c, header-files, microcontroller, keil

I'm learning to program 8051 microcontrollers, but have run into some difficulties regarding the 'header files'.

Basically, I took the header file from Keil for my specific microcontroller(AT89S52), and plugged it into a header file in my IDE with a '.h' ending. This was not the issue though.

The problem occurs when I attempt to compile and link my work, where the built-in debugger claims that the terms "`sfr`" and "`sbit`" are unknown. In specific, the debugger says

> "error: unknown type name 'sbit'"
>
> "error: unknown type name 'sfr'".

I do understand where this is coming from, as these are not defined in the given header file text which I pulled from Keil, but regardless, where is my mistake and what is the solution?

I have looked and can't really find an answer online. If you have any questions, I'll attempt to answer them as soon as possible. The link to the header file is below. I'm working in an IDE called 'Code Blocks'.

http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/c51/atmel/regx52.h

Comment: Try to find in other header file where is defined `sfr` or `sbit` (something like `#define sfr ...` or `typedef ... sfr` and include it before the header causing trouble...

Comment: I edited the header file using #define sbit, and #define sfr, but I'm a little cautious to do that as I'm unsure if that will change the function of these terms.

Comment: What do you mean by "plugged it into a header file"? It sounds like you deleted the original content and replaced it by the other one. So please  give details on how exactly.

Comment: Please edit additional information into your question, instead of adding it in comments. Use the formatting features offered by editing questions instead of comments.

Comment: Making your own version of sft and sbit is unlikely to help. Tracking the root of the problem is what is needed.

Comment: Is there something like a HelloWorld for your environment?

Comment: @Yunnosch Defining the terms did remove the errors, but as you stated, I highly doubt it was beneficial to solving this issue. If you do program microcontrollers, can you describe to me how you obtain and implement header files in hopes that I may find the step which may have caused this issue. And in addition, can you check whether or not your header files include sbit or sfr. Thanks.

Comment: I obtain header files by looking into whatever is provided by the chip supplier or the compiler supplier and I make sure that I use headers which are meant to be used for the chip. And I read some documentation which headers are needed for which purpose. And I look for HelloWorld programs or tutorials available for that chip and the tool chain I use.

Comment: If reading doucmentation fails I would probably look for a different toolchain or even a different chip. If I am stuck for some reason with what I have I tend to sigh frustratedly and start grepping through all the available headers for the symbols which seem undefined.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is it dedicated for your microcontroller, or are you using some random general-purpose compiler?

Comment: I think this is  keil-ism something specific to their compiler/language that if notthing else prevents porting code to other compilers which I assume is what is going on here.  Should either stick with the one compiler or write portable code.

Comment: @el.pescado I am using a GNU (GCC) Compiler, which is standard for Code Blocks. I believe that this is general purpose, but also seems like a pretty standard compiler for most IDE applications.

Comment: @old_timer That would make sense. I will look into a different header file and do my research. I could imagine that the makers of the file at Keil used additional external information that they assumed would be used in the compilation process to specify what the terms sbit and sfr mean.

Comment: I would assume they simply added those data types to the language (for that target).

Comment: @MischiefCity I think the problem is that your `gcc` is configured to build binaries for PC, not for microcontroller. In order to build binaries for microcontrollers you need special version of compiler targetting that platform. That's why you get errors about missing type definitions - those definitions doesn't exist on PC, so PC compilers don't know about them.

Answer (score 1):

the header file you linked is not for the microcontroller you specified in your text.  you can not repurpose header files from one product to another.   you must find the correct header files for your specific microcontroller.

Comment: But regardless, assuming I did have the correct header file from Keil for my specific microcontroller, how would I solve my issue of sbit and sfr causing errors in the compilation and linking process? From what I've seen, adjusting the given header file produced by Keil is not correct, so what is the alternative method, and will I have to add additional header files to define these terms?

Comment: ok, sorry, i read your question rather fast, and would have commented in the comment section with the others, but i'm still a few points away.

i think your problem is in the compiler.   here is what i would do, if i were you.

(1) use the Keil Compiler if you have a license available.  

(2) use the GCC SDCC compiler.

(3) if you have to use CodeBlocks (no one does embedded work in real world with this tool AFAIK), then fix the codeBlocks compiler options.     

this looks promising:

http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mcclurel/CodeBlocks-SDCC_Tutorial_10-13-2013.pdf

Comment: the more i look into this the more im sure your compiler is not configured correctly.  CodeBlocks is a great tool for learning, and basic software dev, but it's not really an embedded tool.  im sure you can get it to work, perhaps with the colorado link i just posted, but you might have better luck and less stress with a compilier that's intended for 8051 development.   check this out if you're interested:  https://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/index.html

Comment: Would you recommend using the Keil UVision IDE? I've read that most of these headers are already defined there, which would probably be more beneficial to my cause than using Code Blocks, which in my opinion is more oriented towards user input output type programs.

Comment: i dont know that one in particular, but since it's Keil, i agree with your idea that it would be more beneficial generally.   i would go that route.